# Vector Triple Product from Lagrange’s Identity

Tags: vectors, cross-product

How can one obtain (5.12) from (5.11)?

> The relation
>   $$\tag{5.11}
> \left( \mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b}\right) \cdot \left( \mathbf{c} \times \mathbf{d}\right)
> = \left( \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{c}\right) \left( \mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{d}\right) - 
> \left( \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{d}\right)  \left( \mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{c}\right)
> $$
>   is called the *Identity of Langrange*. From ($5.11$) follows
>   $$\tag{5.12}
> \left(\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b} \right) \times \mathbf{c} = \left(\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{c} \right)\mathbf{b} - \left( \mathbf{b}\cdot \mathbf{c} \right)\mathbf{a}
> $$
>   Can someone give a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key observation is that if $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are two vectors such that $\mathbf{A}\cdot \mathbf{C} = \mathbf{B}\cdot \mathbf{C}$ for all vectors $\mathbf{C}$, then $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{B}$. This fact will be used here.

If $\mathbf{d}$ is an arbitrary vector, then $$[(\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{b})\times \mathbf{c}]\cdot \mathbf{d} = (\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{b})\cdot (\mathbf{c}\times \mathbf{d})$$ Use (5.11) to obtain the equivalent expression $$[(\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{c})\,\mathbf{b} - (\mathbf{b}\cdot \mathbf{c})\,\mathbf{a}]\cdot \mathbf{d}$$ Since $\mathbf{d}$ was arbitrary, we deduce (5.12).